# HTTPS WP site switched to HTTP Squarespace site and wont redirect

Tags: http, https, squarespace

We recently switched an https WP site to a squarespace site that is http.

We've updated Google Search Console and waited 3 days.  But our landing page is still https so anyone who finds us on Google can't get to the site.  What can we do to (1) teach google to use http or (2) redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a few things going on here, but primarily what you need is https:// on your Squarespace website. To do that, head over to http://cloudflare.com and setup your domain name DNS with Cloudflare. Cloudflare offers free SSL and it DOES work with Squarespace. Try that out and see what you come up with. I'm using it on my site, as well as clients, and it works great.